# plot timeSeriex chart with multipleDataSet OR pass a Collection Object in JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Actually I have to plot timeSeries using *JasperReports*.

How to generate the time series graph for different data sets? I am able to generate the time series graph when i have one data set to plot over a period of time. However when i have multiple data set to plot then i am facing problem.

I am using List data source.

```
public class KpiReportPoints {
    private String deviceDn;
    private List<KpiReportPoint> kpiPoints;
}

public class KPiReportPoint{
    private Date time;
    private Double value;

   public Date getTime() {
      return time;
   }

   public void setTime(Date time) {
      this.time = time;
   }

   public Double getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(Double value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return time.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      boolean equal = false;
      if (obj instanceof KPIReportPoint){
         KPIReportPoint point  = (KPIReportPoint) obj;
         equal = time.equals(point.getTime())&& value.equals(point.getValue());
      }
      return equal;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(KPIReportPoint o) {
      return this.time.compareTo(o.getTime());
   }
}
```

Both the above classes have their getters and setters and all are public ,so no problem according to me is there in the definition of each. I am passing the populated 
`List<KpiReportPoints>` as `JRBEanCollectionDataSource(kpiReportpointsList)`;

Now below is my jrxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="KPI_Reports" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <subDataset name="Dataset">
        <field name="time" class="java.util.Date"/>
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="X_UNIT" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Date"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Y_UNIT" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["%"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="REPORT_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["KPI Report"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="from" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="to" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="deviceDn" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="kpiPoints" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="513" y="0" width="253" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="443">
            <timeSeriesChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true" customizerClass="com.ipaccess.nos.business.pm.impl.KPIChartCustomizer">
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="766" height="443" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true"/>
                    <chartTitle position="Top">
                        <font size="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Courier-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_NAME}]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend position="Bottom"/>
                </chart>
                <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Second">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{kpiPoints})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <timeSeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{deviceDn}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <timePeriodExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}]]></timePeriodExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
                    </timeSeries>
                </timeSeriesDataset>
                <timeSeriesPlot isShowLines="true" isShowShapes="true">
                    <plot labelRotation="90.0"/>
                    <timeAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$P{X_UNIT}]]></timeAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$P{Y_UNIT}]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont>
                                <font size="10"/>
                            </labelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <domainAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{from}]]></domainAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <domainAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{to}]]></domainAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </timeSeriesPlot>
            </timeSeriesChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This issue is jrxml compiles fine but on trying to generate a report it throws the exception :

```
[#|2014-10-10T09:59:05.769+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=290;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : time
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:127)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:100)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillData
```

I have been completely mad with this issue and not able to find even a single problem in the above code which may cause this. If any of you is able to see that and have any time faced this error then please give me some clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: The thing with sub datasets is that it has its own fields and require its own datasource, which in your case is `List`. Although more details are required to get to a solution, need to look at your `JRXML` and the code you use to fill it. Probably than conclusion can be drwan.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here.

```
public class KpiReportPoints {
    private String deviceDn;
    private List<KpiReportPoint> kpiPoints;
}
```

You are passing the list of `KpiReportPoints`, which is fine, but the list would futher contain `private List<KpiReportPoint> kpiPoints;` which is the list itself.

The problem with `Jasper Report` is that it would recognize `JRBEanCollectionDataSource(kpiReportpointsList)` and would fetch `deviceDn` and `kpiPoints`. Now since you have a field `$F{deviceDn}` and `deviceDn` being string is a perfect match. No problem uptill here.

**Problem Part :**
When it would fetch `kpiPoints` there is noway `Jasper Report` will fetch values inside from that list and fill report as it is `not the primitive type`.

**Solution :**
I would suggest you use `Custom Data Source` or `redesign` your report so that it recognizes `kpiPoints` list and further would fetch values from that list and fill report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But I guess won't the below code :          <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{kpiPoints})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>                              be doing that part . Like iterating this kpiPoints list as a dataSource and fetching the fields which I have described in dataSet . I am very new to jasper so not sure if this is correct or not . Could you also please share any good example on customDataSource

Comment: Now having looked at you `jrxml` more carefully, I don't think you require custom datasource.The code you mentioned in the comment is the way to go. But I do think the design though as you said compiles, is probably the area of concern. I suggest you revisit the design, compile it on different platforms to see if there is a problem there. With the current code of jrxml you should not have any problems, but I think you are missing some part in there.

Comment: Can anybody who has very good knowledge of jasper help me wih it .. IT's really getting on my nerves as I am literally stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

You said:
"I am passing the populated List as JRBEanCollectionDataSource(kpiReportpointsList);"

You should pass it as a List because the template expects List in:

```
<datasetRun subDataset="Dataset">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{kpiPoints})]] </dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

You must have in java:

```
List<KPiReportPoint> yourList = new ArrayList<KPiReportPoint>();
// fill the list with values
// ...............
// end fill

mapParams.put("kpiPoints", yourList);
// fill the compiled report
JasperFillManager.fillReport(yourReport, mapParams, new JREmptyDataSource());
```